# Запрет ввода зарезервированных системой имен

Tags: c#

Как запретить ввод зарезервированных системой имен? допустим aux,con. В С++ использовал `#include <experimental/filesystem>`  соответственно проверку на наличие файла и

```
if (!is_regular_file(filename))
    {
        cout << "Not a regular file!";
        return 1;
    }
```

Как обернуть это дело на C#?
Вот код, к примеру:

```
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                {
                    if (file.Length == 0)
                    {
                        lock (fileLock)
                        {

                            File.WriteAllLines(path, mass.Select(t => t.ToString()));
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Можно просто отлавливать ArgumentException при попытке открыть файл. Если оно возникает и при этом путь не содержит запрещенных символов и не пустой, остается что он зарезервированный..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для проверки на зарезервированное имя необходимо отбросить расширение и путь, т. к. `D:\NUL.txt` [также является зарезервированным именем](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx). В интернете советуют просто держать список зарезервированных имён и сравнивать с ним, отбросив путь и расширение. Но более простым способом на моей системе (Windows 10 build 1709, .NET 4.7.1) является просто

```
static bool IsDevice(string name) => Path.GetFullPath(name).StartsWith(@"\\.\");
```

Проверка:

```
foreach (var name in new[]
         { "CON", "LPT", "LPT1", @"D:\NUL.txt",
           @"D:\COM.txt", @"Z:\TEMP\lPt4.exe", "NUL:", "command.nul" })
{
    var isReserved = IsDevice(name);
    Console.WriteLine($"Name {name} is {isReserved ? "reserved" : "not reserved")}");
}
```

выдаёт

```
Name CON is reserved
Name LPT is not reserved
Name LPT1 is reserved
Name D:\NUL.txt is reserved
Name D:\COM.txt is not reserved
Name Z:\TEMP\lPt4.exe is reserved
Name NUL: is reserved
Name command.nul is not reserved
```

Comment: Возможно, для некоторых применений нужно еще добавить `&& !name.StartsWith(@"\\.\")`. А для других - не нужно.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: насколько я понимаю, `"\\.\"` в любом случае означает устройство, а не файл. По идее, стоит переименовать функцию в `IsDevice`?

Comment: Думаю, да, стоит.

Answer (score 0):

На сколько помню, то нет такой библиотеки у C#. Можно попробовать, так:

```
string[] reserved_names = {"CON", "PRN", "AUX", "NUL", "COM1", "COM2", "COM3", "COM4", "COM5", "COM6", "COM7", "COM8", "COM9", "LPT1", "LPT2", "LPT3", "LPT4", "LPT5", "LPT6", "LPT7", "LPT8", "LPT9"};
```

...

```
for(int i = 0; i != 22; i++) {
    if(FileName == reserved_names[i]) {
        return "Bad!";
    }
}
```